# Example which proves that a closed subset of an incomplete metric space need not be complete.

Tags: metric-spaces

We know that a closed subset of a complete metric space is complete.
But I want to find a closed subset $A$ of an incomplete metric space $(X,d)$ such that $A$ is not complete.

Comment: Why not take $A=X$?

Comment: The set $\mathbb{Q}$ is a metric space that isn't complete. The set $[0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ and is not complete.

Comment: A simple example is $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, $A=\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be an irrational number and use the interval $(-\infty,x] \cap \mathbf Q$, which is the same as $(-\infty,x) \cap \mathbf Q$ since $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\mathbf Q,|\cdot|)$ be a metric space which is incomplete. Consider $\mathbf Q$ to be a subspace of $\mathbf Q$.

$\mathbf Q$ is closed in $\mathbf Q$, and also incomplete.